# What is the word for highly disliking something but even when you are told you dont have to, you still do it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I play football. However, I dislike going and sometimes I just dont want to play it. But whenever someone tells me that i do not have to do it or that I can stop when I want, I put all the work into it.

One reason I can assume is that my father played ball and I am the last son, he and my mother want me to play but I have "mixed" feelings to say the least. Whenever I constantly tell my parents that I dislike football, they obviously get very saddened and I dont care about that in particular. The strange thing is that when I get the choice alone and with nobody around, I always play ball because it makes me happy. But whenever I'm told that I have to, it feels like a chore. I can't explain this to my parents and I feel the need to get this off my chest as I am heading out soon.

Comment: What makes you think there should be a single word for this situation?

Comment: Hey Kate. I just wanted to say that I dont completely understand the question you're asking. But as far as I understand it, I would like to say that I am new to this site and I'm on here because I am finding words that mean something contrary to specific feelings. There are alot of words out there and they usually have specific meanings, this one could be no exception and so I'm left to assume that there is a word for this. If there is more than one I would prefer the answer instead of a question under another question. Thank you.

Comment: People quite often post on these forums asking "What is the  word for (some complicated idea)?" If the idea is complicated, there probably isn't a way of expressing it in a single word.

Comment: Sounds exactly like being *contrary* or *oppositional*.

Comment: @KateBunting  Do you have any recommendations? I appreciate the help and advice, I'm really grateful that you are helping people get smarter and understanding by the hour. Do you think you could help me fix the issue by telling me what i need to change?

Comment: Thank you very much @YosefBaskin

Comment: You don't need to change anything, just accept that you probably can't express that idea in a single word.

Comment: @KateBunting I understand, thank you.

Comment: @YosefBaskin actually, I have a request. Could you use those in a sentence? It is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence where you'd use the word (or phrase)?

Comment: @Laurel Who is this question for if I may ask?

Comment: "I'm trying to help you, but because you're being either contrary or oppositional, you 
fight back no matter what."

Comment: You, @White. It's not even clear what part of speech you'd be looking for, so there are a lot of potential answers, which doesn't work for our site. See the relevant [tag wiki info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for some more information you can include.

Comment: OT. Tell your parents that you are not a child and that you need them to let you grow up in your own way. Tell them to stop loading you with their expectations. Tell them to trust you, because they did a good job. Don't wait for a reply, but go out for several hours. Whether you continue to play ball, is your decision alone.

Comment: Something like *conflicted* or *ambivalent* expresses having two different feelings about the same thing, but are nowhere near precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

> The strange thing is that when I get the choice alone and with nobody
> around, I always play ball because it makes me happy. But whenever I'm
> told that I have to, it feels like a chore.

I'm not sure it qualifies as a single word, but I suggest:

**Love-hate** (adj.)

> Feeling or showing a mixture of love and hate [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/love-hate)

> Characterized simultaneously by feelings of love and hate [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/love-hate)

**Love-hate relationship** (n.)

> Strong feelings about someone or something that are a mixture of love
> and hate
>
> *He had a **love-hate relationship** with London.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/love-hate-relationship)

> A state of ambivalence in which one feels both love and hate for
> someone or something:
>
> *Transylvania has something of a **love-hate relationship** with Dracula tourism.*
>
> *The **love-hate relationship** between directors and actors is entertainingly dissected in this kiss-and-tell memoir from the
> directing frontlines.* [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/love-hate-relationship)

---

> CRITICAL THINKING CHALLENGE
>
> Name three attitude objects (a person, a place, and an idea) about
> which you have some version of a dual attitude, such as a **love-hate**
> attitude toward a person who both attracts and repels you. [T. Heinzen
> et al.; *Social Psychology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Social_Psychology/UUVBDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22love-hate%20attitude%22&pg=PA170&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> The image that has been just discussed, that is the idea, fantasised
> by a citizen, of putting a tongue into each one of Coriolanus' wounds
> is highly symptomatic of the **love-hate** attitude through which the
> Romans are tied to their favourite: on the one had, this image hardly
> conceals an impulse to 'sexual appropriation', on the other it
> disguises an intent to punish by ... [F. Bondi et al.; *The Wounded
> Body*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Wounded_Body/m9JjEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22love-hate%20attitude%22&pg=PA235&printsec=frontcover) (2022)

> I realize I have a **love-hate relationship** with sports. I love the
> sudden rush I feel when my favorite football team is down one
> touchdown, and I can barely hear my thoughts above my family's cheers
> and screams. On the other hand, I've grown to truly dislike sports,
> and even with all the fun and joy it may bring, sports have become a
> reflection of what Black culture is supposed to represent. [Rachel
> Laws Myers; *Race and Sports*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Race_and_Sports_A_Reference_Handbook/cQTHEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20love-hate%20relationship%22%20with%20sports&pg=RA1-PT26&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

Answer (score 0):

The most common word for coexistence of love and hate for something/someone in psychology is **Affection Ambivalence**.

It is [described](https://exploringyourmind.com/affection-ambivalence-when-love-and-hate-coexist/) as a type of complex emotion of contradiction and tension. However, looking for a simple term, as stated in OP, **[mixed emotion/feeling](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mixed-feelings-emotions)** can work for explaining the situation.